# Api to find out if a photo is clicked from photo or of a real person

Tags: api, flutter, artificial-intelligence

I am working on an app in flutter that requires me to verify if a photo is clicked from a "non living photo" or of a "live person". Is there a way to detect it from an api or some plugin by looking at its exif data or something. Actually I also welcome the idea of doing it.

Elaboration:

I am doing face recognition of a person to authenticate some thing but the photo is recognized even if the photo is clicked from a photo and I want to avoid this. By the way I am using azure for Face Recognization

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate "of a live person"?

Comment: Pardon my english. We have made an app in which we verify if a person has marked attendance from the company's location or not. So we first verify the location and recognizes the photo of a person through azure face recognition. But many people do buddy punching by providing their login credentials to some one else and asking him to click a photo from his photo saved in the gallery of his or some other person's phone. Since the photo is clicked from a photo visible on the screen of some phone. They bypasses facial recognition test. So I want to know as i stated

Comment: I am doing face recognition of a person to authenticate some thing but the photo is recognized even if the photo is clicked from a photo and I want to avoid this. By the way I am using azure for Face Recognization

Comment: Some thoughts, 1) Do bio-metric punching like finger print authentication 2) On facial recognition step, ask them to do some random things like: close your eyes, rotate your head to right or something like that.

Comment: Well the authentication is not at all of importance to the employees but for the company. The company wants to know if the person has really clicked the photo or it is clicked by some other person when the person was not present in the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is said spoofing detection in Facial Recognition or liveliness of the photo. More explanation here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/anti-spoofing-techniques-for-face-recognition-solutions-4257c5b1dfc9

Comment: How you detect live face detection...can you please share some detail